# Notion of Neumann boundary conditions over the boundary

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ a convex polygonal domain, where $\partial\Omega = \Gamma_N\cup \Gamma_D,$ with $\Gamma_N\cap\Gamma_D = \emptyset$ and $u\in\mathbb{P}_1(\overline{\Omega}).$

If $\partial u/\partial n = 0 \quad \text{on} \quad \Gamma_N,$ can we say that $u = $constant over $\Gamma_N$ ?

Answer (score 0):

No. You can only conclude that $u$ is constant in directions perpendicular to $\Gamma_N$.

Take $\Omega=(-1,1)^2$ with $\Gamma_N = (-1,+1) \times\{-1,+1\}$ = upper and lower edge of the square. Now take $u(x_1,x_2) = x_1$.